# An error occurred while using the gcc command

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, undefined-reference

"undefined reference to 'func~'" error..

I'm new to that program, so I can't figure out the reason for the error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FbWC.png)

Comment: How are you calling gcc? And also post the error as text into the question rather than linking to an image

Comment: Don't paste screenshots if you can also put the text directly into your posting.  Also, you ask about how to fix an error, without showing the code which causes the error to appear.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to add `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: That will fix the warnings, but not the error that the OP is asking about

Comment: @ChrisTurner why?

Comment: because the errors are related to linking and including extra headers won't fix that